# How do I format my SD card via terminal/Termux?

Tags: external-sd, terminal, termux, formatting

I'm running a MIUI 12.5.5 xiaomi.eu ROM on a rooted Redmi Note 9 Pro. I'm trying to format my 128GB micro SD Card via Settings > Storage > Format SD Card, but this causes the device to reboot. I suspect it's something to do with the ROM, so I'd like to format it via terminal or Termux if needed.

How should I proceed? Also, should I format it to exFAT or FAT32?

Comment: [@meganukebmp](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4366113) is looking for testers on Partitioning SD card. sounds right on cue for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARNING:** for devices with **UFS** flash memory **only**

- from MIUI

  ```
  mkfs.exfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
  ```
- from TWRP

  ```
  mkexfatfs /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
  ```

(`mmcblk1p1` for devices with eMMC flash memory)

Comment: On devices with eMMC, `mmcblk0` is usually the internal storage. And `mmcblk1` is the SD card. Better add warning in your answer. Also AFAI have seen, eMMC storage is enumerated as `mmcblk[N]`, while UFS storage is enumerated as `sd[N]`. In the latter case the SD card is likely to be `mmcblk0` which you've stated.

Comment: Is there a way to confirm what is the correct form for my device?

Comment: `cat /proc/memory_type`

Comment: I don't seem to have a `/proc/memory_type` file, nor anything resembling it in `/proc`. However, `cat /proc/partitions` displays, among others, `mmcblk0` and `mmcblk0p1`. Is that enough to be sure I won't format my internal storage accidentally?

Comment: remove the SD Card and compare the difference

Comment: Apparently, removing the SD Card makes them both disappear, what could this mean?

Comment: assuming with both you mean mmcblk0 and mmcblk0p1: mmcblk0 is the disk, mmcblk0**p1** is the first partition on that disk. you should also see block size (KiB)